# Change site.url to localhost during jekyll local development

Tags: hyperlink, jekyll

My jekyll blog template have links to resources and pages like so:

```
{{ site.url }}/my-page.html
```

This works well in deployment, but when I run `jekyll serve` in development, all of the links point to the live page instead of the development page.

```
my-site-url/my-page.html

# But I want this in development
localhost:4000/my-page.html
```

Is there a way to make jekyll use a different `{{ site.url }}` in development?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

This is a common problem between different Jekyll environments.

### Some explanations

We need to understand `site.url` and `site.baseurl` and in which situation we need them.
Those variables don't serve the same purpose.

#### `site.url`

By default, this variable is only used in page head for the `canonical` header and the `RSS link`. It's also used in the xml feed to point to site resources as the software that will manage this feed doesn't know resource's urls.

This variable is only necessary for external systems.

#### `site.baseurl`

This variable indicates the root folder of your Jekyll site. By default it is set to `""` (empty string). That means that your Jekyll site is at the root of `http://example.com`.

If your Jekyll site lives in `http://example.com/blog`, you have to set `site.baseurl` to `/blog` (**note the slash**). This will allow assets (css, js) to load correctly.

See how assets are loaded in you head :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

that can also be :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/main.css">
```

### Working in different environments

Now you have to test your site locally and to deploy it in production. Sometimes, the `baseurl` is different and the `jekyll build` may not work out of the box in one of those environment.

Here we have two solutions :

#### Use `jekyll serve`

Let's imagine that your site lives in a github repository and is served at `https://username.github.io/myProject`.

You can setup the `baseurl` to `/myProject`. and test your site locally with `jekyll serve`, your site will be served at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/myProject/`

#### Use multiple configuration files

If, for one reason or another, you cannot use `jekyll serve`, you can set a configuration file for both environment and `jekyll build` depending on where you are deploying.

Let's say we have the local site served at `http://localhost` and the production site served at `https://username.github.io/myProject`.

We leave the `_config.yml` with `url: https://username.github.io` and `baseurl: /myProject`

We create a new `_config_dev.yml` with only `url: https://localhost` and `baseurl: ""`

Now to test locally :

```
jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml
```

or

```
jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml --watch
```

When pushed on production, the `jekyll build` command will use the default `_config.yml`.

Comment: For some reasons, the a pre-made jekyll theme I downloaded use `site.url` to prepend the css / js resources. Is this a bad idea? Should I change everything to `site.baseurl`, and use `site.url` only for canonical link and xml feed?

Comment: Of course ! `{{site.baseurl}}/asset` for assets and `{{site.url}}/{{site.baseurl}}/ressource` for external needs. And maybe you can approve my answer.

Comment: Perhaps `{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}` instead since `site.baseurl` already has a pre-pended slash?

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's `{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}`.

Comment: But why it does not append `/blog` to post URL? I still get the broken URL of the post like `/2014/12/12/mypost-name`. It actually broke the link since i have everything inside blog folder.

Comment: Jekyll doesn't prepend `site.url` automatically to `post.url`. You have to do it yourself : `{{ site.url }}{{post.url }}`

Comment: @DavidJacquel How about we set `site.url` to `http://requestly.github.io/public` and define another variable in config like site.rootUrl to `http://requestly.github.io`. Because there are so many references in the theme which needs to be updated. Do you see any problem with this approach. I am wondering why theme designers did not use baseurl by default. There should be some reason behind that.

Comment: I have the same question and I don't think the accepted answer actually answers it. Is it possible to access the host and port of `jekyll serve` from inside the generation logic? This would be especially useful if you use `jekyll serve --host myhost --port 1234`.

Comment: @basszwo the answer is yes. But, you can take time to ask a real question on SO ; I'll be pleased to give you an real answer.

Comment: @david-jacquel Here ya go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487883/how-to-set-the-url-site-variable-to-host-and-port-specified-in-jekyll-serve Looking forward.

Comment: I came to this question because I had the opposite problem. After reading this answer, I realized that `jekyll build` uses the production url, whereas `jekyll serve` will use localhost (regardless of what the `url` setting is in `_config.yml`). Hope this helps someone!

Comment: `jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`: first one for prod, second for dev? It should also work with `serve` in dev: `jekyll serve --config _config_dev.yml`

Comment: I used `jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`. 

For url I used: `http://localhost:4000`

Answer (score 0):

The question and the good answer is a bit old, but I think still from need.

I also run in that issue on jekyll v4.2. I have three differnt environments, with differnt `url` and `baseurl` in my config-files (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27400343/10655742) from @david-jacquel) can be combined.

|  | Production | Dev | GitLab Page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| url | https://company.tld | http://localhost:8017 | https://n13org.gitlab.io |
| baseurl | / | / | /demo/company-tld |
| config | `_config.yml` | `_config.dev.yml` | `_config.gitlab.yml` |

I was not happy with the handling / behavior of `url` and `baseurl` together with CSS / JS / images / internal links to posts and pages ... I tried many ways also in combination with the `relative_url` [filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/).

I end up, with writting a small ruby [plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/) for jekyll. The plugin is just ruby code inside the `_plugins` folder.

The plugin code from file `tag_website_url.rb` will create a new [jekyll tag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/) which can be used in `html` or `markdown` (md) files with `{% website_url %}` or `{% website_url noprotocol %}`. The second tag will omit the protocol (e.g. http or https).

```rb
require 'uri'

module Jekyll
  class WebsiteUrlTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text.strip
      tokens = tokens
    end

    def render(context)
      site = context.registers[:site]

      uri = URI.parse("#{site.config["url"]}#{site.config["baseurl"]}")

      str_uri_port = uri.port && uri.port != 80 && uri.port != 443 ? ":" + uri.port.to_s : ""
      websiteurl = uri.host + str_uri_port + uri.path
      websiteurl.prepend(uri.scheme + '://') if @text != "noprotocol"

      websiteurl.sub(/(\/)+$/,'')
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('website_url', Jekyll::WebsiteUrlTag)
```

The code can handle also PORTS which are often used for localhost development. The ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) will be removed. The settings from the config files are stored inside the variables `site.config`