# Defining Variable Configuration in _config.yml in jekyll powered website

Tags: config, jekyll, static-site

There are multiple sets of configuration which you may want to execute when you are running the site locally while when your site is running on server (say Github).

I have defined similar set of configuration in my `_config.yml` file like this

```
title: Requestly
locale: en_US
description: Chrome Extension to modify HTTP(s) Requests
logo: site-logo.png
search: true
env: dev

config:
  dev:
    url: http://localhost:4000
  prod:
    url: http://requestly.github.io/blog

url: site.config[site.env].url // Does not work
```

I have used `{{ site.url }}` everywhere else in my templates, layouts and
posts.

How can I define `site.url` in my `_config.yml` file whose value depends upon the `config` and `env` defined in the same file.

**PS**: I know one of the ways is to change `{{ site.url }}` to `{{ site.config[site.env].url }}` in all the files. That should probably work.

I just want to know how to use variables in `_config.yml`. Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot use variables in a _config file.

You can find more informations here : [Change site.url to localhost during jekyll local development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386169/change-site-url-to-localhost-during-jekyll-local-development/)

Comment: Thanks @David. You are all over answering Jekyll based questions

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Jekyll 3.8.0 or later version now. Please give that a try

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I just pegged my version to 3.8.0 but the dereferencing is not happening.