# How to set the `url` site variable to host and port specified in `jekyll serve --host …`?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

How can I access the host and port that `jekyll serve` runs the site on from inside a jekyll plugin or so, to load my assets with absolute links from the right place?

When I run `jekyll serve --host example.local --port 1234` I want to change the `url` var (set to example.com in _config.yml) to the given host and port so that I can use `{{ site.url }}/css/site.css` without getting my production assets. Also it would be nice to get the default `localhost:4000` when nothing else is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the full url with port, you can do :

```
{% assign fullUrlWithPort = site.host | prepend:"http://" | append:":" | append: site.port %}
```

By default `{{ fullUrlWithPort }}` will give you `http://127.0.0.1:4000`.

If you launch a `jekyll serve --host myhost --port 1234` it will give you a `http://myhost:1234`