# GitHub pages loading unknown style.css

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

I've made a few sites with GitHub Pages before, but I still don't feel like I'm on solid footing.

Right now I'm trying to make a project page, and while it works just fine locally, GitHub Pages seems to be loading some other CSS file, which has style directives that I don't recognize. For instance, there's a line in the loaded CSS `ol ol, ul ol { list-style-type: lower-roman; }`, yet a search of my repository shows that I've never even set a `list-style-type` anywhere in the repository.

I started off using scss files from the jekyll-theme-cayman theme, and I've also tried creating a pre-compiled style.css file, and setting up a style.scss file in the assets/css folder with a class to search for to indicate that I can change the css that way, but I'm still not seeing the relationship between the style.css file that's loaded by the site and any of the files in my repository.

The site is at https://jaguillette.github.io/fabulousTime/, the stylesheet that's being loaded is here: https://jaguillette.github.io/assets/css/style.css, and the repository is here: https://github.com/jaguillette/fabulousTime/tree/eca2827b63a3e3fc4ea70a7310fad95e5e68ba75 (linking to the current commit for posterity). The site is being served from the docs folder in the repository.

Comment: You should be using the `github-pages` gem, that would probably fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you're pulling **jaguillette.github.io** style sheet, not **jaguillette.github.io/fabulousTime/** one.

In your **/docs/_config.yml**, use `baseurl: "/fabulousTime"`.

Comment: That was it, thank you! Now I just have to make sure I don't forget `--baseurl ""` when I'm developing locally...

Comment: [Some useful tips on how to run jekyll in multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27400343/1548376)