# ERROR `/' not found. ERROR `/blog/assets/main.css' not found.

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Noob here. Recently setup jekyll with github pages and the site is functioning on the github server however, since i pushed to github I am now having problems when I enter jekyll serve in to the shell and make any changes in my blog posts md files. The following message appears in the command line and a 404 page not found on my local server... All I did was add some content to one of my posts.. Didn't change any front matter either, have since undone any changes and still i get the same error...

```
tim@ubuntu16:~/github/blog$ jekyll serve
```

`Configuration file: /home/tim/github/blog/_config.yml
            Source: /home/tim/github/blog
       Destination: /home/tim/github/blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.199 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/tim/github/blog'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000blog/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2018-04-08 21:56:21] ERROR`/' not found.

[2018-04-08 21:56:21] ERROR `/blog/assets/main.css' not found.
[2018-04-08 21:56:21] ERROR`/blog/assets/minima-social-icons.svg' not found.
`

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where it breaks : "*Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000blog/*"

In `_config.yml`, set `baseurl: /blog`

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Changed blog to /blog..  Now I am getting this:

Comment: [2018-04-09 10:24:07] ERROR `/' not found.
[2018-04-09 10:24:07] ERROR `/favicon.ico' not found.

Comment: When you try to reach http://127.0.0.1:4000/blog/ ? Can we see your code somewhere ?

Comment: I changed baseurl to the default "" and now it works... Strange.  Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386169/change-site-url-to-localhost-during-jekyll-local-development/27400343#27400343